# How can a tourist order a dabbawala lunch?

Tags: india, food-and-drink, mumbai

I've recently learned about an amazing [traditional lunch delivery service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dabbawala) in Mumbai:

> The dabbawalas constitute a lunchbox delivery and return system that delivers hot lunches from homes and restaurants to people at work in India, especially in Mumbai. The lunchboxes are picked up in the late morning, delivered predominantly using bicycles and railway trains, and returned empty in the afternoon. They are also used by meal suppliers in Mumbai, who pay them to ferry lunchboxes with ready-cooked meals from central kitchens to customers and back.

Is it possible for a tourist to order a dabbawala lunch?

Comment: Are you looking for a one time delivery or a daily delivery (over a span of at least a week)? I doubt you will get a one time service. However there maybe restaurants that utilize the service to deliver their food. This link should shed some light about how it works. https://popupcity.net/dabbawalla-hot-lunch-delivery-by-mumbais-fastest/

Comment: @nightgaunt one time delivery or going somewhere where they deliver food

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dabbawalas are a monthly service and getting one-time delivery is generally not possible. Also, the dabbawalas don't cook the food themselves they just deliver home cook food made by you to your loved ones.

As a tourist, I doubt whether you would be cooking and delivering your own food in tiffin boxes.

But if you would like to know more or just see how they function, I noticed that on their website there is something called a day with dabbawala.Maybe you can avail this service http://mumbaidabbawala.in/a-day-with-dabbawala/

Enjoy your stay in India.